# Is it possible to pattern-match an Iterator in Scala?

Tags: scala, loops, generics, iterator, pattern-matching

Is it possible to pattern-match an Iterator in Scala?
**iter** and **s** below seems to be just `Any`, but I need to make them typed, to call the loop method or process them anyway.
(I guess that this may be related to type erasure, but...)

```
def loop(iterator: Iterator[Any], acc: String): String = {

  iterator.next() match {
    case Iterator @ iter => loop(iter, acc)?????? can I match type of element here?
    case String @ s => s ?????? can I match type of element here?
  }
}
```

Comment: Both **Any**, and type checks are code smells. It may be worth to rethink your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the type of a value, write

```
case iter: Iterator[_] => ...
case s: String => ...
```

What you wrote

```
case Iterator @ iter
```

would only match when the value is `object Iterator`, the companion object of `trait Iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntax mistake

```
case iter: Iterator[Any] => loop(iter, acc)
case s: String => s
```